# Electrical outlet smells like metal

Tags: electrical, metal, smell

What should I do if one of my electrical outlets smell like metal. At first I thought it was my surge protector, but I unplugged that. Now I found out its the outlet. I'm scared. I hope it's not something that will burn my house down.

Comment: What do you mean "smells like metal"?  Metals have no smell.

Comment: Turn off the breaker. Make sure the receptacle is dead top & bottom (assuming it is the typical (US) duplex) as there can be a number of situations where one breaker controls the top and another breaker controls the bottom. Then remove the faceplate and carefully remove the receptacle. Take pictures to show the wires (so you can reconnect the same way) and look for any signs of arcing, melting, burning, etc. If there is any indication of any problems, or if the wires are connected via backstabs instead of screw terminals, **replace the receptacle**, preferably with a "screw to clamp" type or

Comment: one of the new receptacles that has built in Wago-style clips. Upload the pictures if you are not sure about anything.

Comment: Did not know about receptacles with Wago-style clips. Will need to keep an eye out for those!

Comment: Does the receptacle feel warm?  What are you plugging into it?

Comment: I've never smelled my outlets....